# What is the smallest positive base 10 integer that can be printed by a program shorter (in characters) than itself?

Tags: number, code-challenge, optimization, self-referential

I think the question as above is clear, but just in case:

- Write a *full* program (not just a function) which prints a positive base 10 integer, optionally followed by a single newline.
- Qualifying programs will be those whose output is longer (**in bytes**) than the source code of the program, measured in bytes (assuming ASCII or UTF-8 encoding for the program source code).

  I.e. the code must be shorter than the number of digits in the resulting number.
- Leading zeros are disallowed under all circumstances. Counting leading zeroes trivialises the problem; ignoring leading zeros unnecessarily complicates the question.
- The winning program will be the qualifying program which prints the integer with the smallest magnitude.

#### Leaderboard snippet

```js
var QUESTION_ID = 67921;
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe"; var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;
function answersUrl(index) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER; }
function commentUrl(index, answers) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER; }
function getAnswers() { jQuery.ajax({ url: answersUrl(answer_page++), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { answers.push.apply(answers, data.items); answers_hash = []; answer_ids = []; data.items.forEach(function(a) { a.comments = []; var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/); answer_ids.push(id); answers_hash[id] = a; }); if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false; comment_page = 1; getComments(); } }); } function getComments() { jQuery.ajax({ url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { if (data.has_more) getComments(); else if (more_answers) getAnswers(); else process(); } }); }
getAnswers();
var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*)(?:,|[-\u2013] ).*?([\d,^!e+]+)(?=\:?[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;
var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
function getAuthorName(a) { return a.owner.display_name; }
function process() { var valid = []; answers.forEach(function(a) { var body = a.body; a.comments.forEach(function(c) { if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body)) body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>'; }); var match = body.replace(/<sup>([^\n<]*)<\/sup>/g, "^$1").replace(/\(\d+(?:\^\d+,)? [\w\s]+\)/g, "").replace(/floor\(10\^(\d+)\/9\)/g, "$1 ones").replace(/(\d+) ones/g, function (_, x) { return Array(+x + 1).join(1); }).match(SCORE_REG); if (match) valid.push({ user: getAuthorName(a), size: +match[2].replace(/,/g, "").replace(/(\d+)\s*\^\s*(\d+)/, function (_, a, b) { return Math.pow(a, b); }).replace(/(\d+)!/, function (_, n) { for (var i = 1, j = 1; i <= n; i++) j *= i; return j; }), language: match[1], link: a.share_link, }); else console.log(body); }); valid.sort(function (a, b) { var aB = a.size, bB = b.size; return aB - bB }); var languages = {}; var place = 1; var lastSize = null; var lastPlace = 1; valid.forEach(function (a) { if (a.size != lastSize) lastPlace = place; lastSize = a.size; ++place; var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html(); answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".") .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user) .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language) .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link); answer = jQuery(answer); jQuery("#answers").append(answer); var lang = a.language; lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text(); languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang.toLowerCase(), user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link}; }); var langs = []; for (var lang in languages) if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang)) langs.push(languages[lang]); langs.sort(function (a, b) { if (a.lang_raw > b.lang_raw) return 1; if (a.lang_raw < b.lang_raw) return -1; return 0; }); for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i) { var language = jQuery("#language-template").html(); var lang = langs[i]; language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang) .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user) .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link); language = jQuery(language); jQuery("#languages").append(language); } }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>body { text-align: left !important} #answer-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } #language-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } table thead { font-weight: bold; } table td { padding: 5px; }</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> 
<div id="language-list"> <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Number 1 on the [Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot). Not bad for a first question...

Comment: Are you saying `<=` the number or `<` the number? From reading the question, I guess `<`, but just in case.

Comment: @Kslkgh Strictly less than, otherwise the question is trivial for programs which implicitly print their last value.

Comment: Too bad Forth doesn't have an exponentiation operator.  8 8 ^ .  Seven bytes; would print an eight digit number—but it would take a lot of bytes to define ^

Comment: In 7, an esolang I made up a while ago but never implemented, the empty program would print `7`. Of course, there's more reason to that than just "because I wanted it to", but it would be a little long to explain here...

Comment: Is `1.0` an integer?

Comment: It's too late now, but future challenges like this might do well to ask for scores stated as log10(number)

Comment: @WGroleau works fine in dc (see my answer below).

Comment: Integer?  Bother.  If it were floating-point, Commodore Basic: `1?π`

Comment: Every Hot Network Question was number 1 at one point :P @trichoplax

Comment: The restriction to UTF-8 is ridiculous and detrimental. Bytes are bytes, no matter the encoding. I strongly recommend that you change the rules, as as they currently are they disallow languages that are not character-based (e.g. Minecraft, Piet, Folders) or have longer UTF-8 byte counts than their "real" (valid according to [this question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7248/should-a-character-encoding-that-cant-actually-be-used-by-a-compiler-interprete)) byte counts (e.g. APL, TI-BASIC, Seriously, Jelly).

Comment: @ZachGates that's not how the HNQ list works. ;)

Comment: @ZachGates Hot Network Questions is sorted by how many "arbitrary hotness points" a question is assigned. This means most questions never get to the top. This question reached over 200 hotness points at one point, keeping all other questions across the network off the number 1 spot.

Comment: @trichoplax I saw it at 367 hotness points at one point, beating everything else I've ever seen (except "Hello, World!" and The Programming Language Quiz).

Comment: I spent some time looking for a language that would somehow print "1" given the empty program. (Or "0", but I'm not sure that counts.) I couldn't find one, but perhaps it's out there? If anybody else knows a language, feel free to take the idea.

Comment: @DavidZ See the Retina answer.

Comment: @Martin ah, there it is. I guess it must have been buried near the bottom when I commented, or else I really really can't read :-P because I definitely didn't see it before.

Comment: This challenge is very clever in that basically any language can participate. IMHO, it should be a standard "first program" like "Hello, World!" and FizzBuzz.

Comment: Ok, but why is the question body and the title inconsistent?

Comment: I like how this user gained all 766 rep from this one question... Nice question.

Comment: That leaderboard snippet is very broken.

Comment: Can it be like 0000100001 when program length is 9 bytes?

Comment: @nrgmsbki4spot1 No, leading zeroes are explicitly disallowed

Comment: @histocrat Yes, `1.0` is an integer. It has _two digits_, so a corresponding program has a _maximum size_ of _one_ Byte. After all `1.0` is just _a representation_ of an element in ℤ, the set of integers. I’m afraid that _expressions_ such as `1×10⁸` or similar do _not_ meet the challenge‘s criteria, though. The evaluation must have been done by your program. See also [my Pascal submission](/a/254237/94076).

Answer (score 206):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina/), score 1

The empty program counts the number of matches of the empty regex in the input (which is the empty string). That's exactly 1 match, so it prints `1`.

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=&input=)

Comment: ... WE HAVE A WINNER.

Comment: Just btw, I'd say the number of matches is infinite. The empty string can repeat an unlimited number of times and be matched infinitely.

Comment: @nicael Luckily, that's not how regex works. ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner that depends on  your regex engine. I've definitely encountered systems that will crap out if you ever try to match the empty string.

Comment: @Sparr Most of the more common flavours can handle empty matches and treat them such that no two matches can start at the same index, but two can end at the same index (so there can be an empty match at the end of a non-empty one, but not at the beginning of a non-empty one and also no two empty matches in the same position).

Comment: I knew this had to be possible in some language... but it never even crossed my mind that that language could be Retina. +1

Comment: @nicael it depends on how you define matches and the number of matches. You could easily provide a definition that doesn't allow to have multiple matches at the same position, which is what is usually done.

Comment: I thought null programs weren't allowed in these challenges?

Comment: @LorenPechtel that rule applies only to quine challenges where the empty program is trivially a solution in most languages. I think it's fair game here, since this empty program actually has non-trivial semantics and Retina does not have this behaviour because of challenges like this but because it's the only consistent generalisation of its behaviour for all single-line programs.

Comment: Holy cow, a 0.  You beautiful genius.

Answer (score 76):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), 10

```
T
```

First attempt at using Pyth. Having had the question clarified, it seems 10 will be the smallest number. In Pyth the letter T starts off as the number 10, so this simply prints `10` which is larger than the length of the source code. You can [try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=T&debug=0).

Comment: I like how your first attempt at using Pyth is just the letter T.

Comment: Well, I thought [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67331/42419) would be the most readable Pyth program I'd see for a while, but *this* is impressively easy to understand.

Comment: This is a polygot, this works in 05AB1E too. http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=VA

Answer (score 62):

## bc, 10

```
A
```

Luckily, `bc` prints the result of the last expression by default.  `A` is interpreted as a hex digit, so results in `10`.

Comment: But there're already (at least) 5 similar answers, including the solution with `A`, because many golfing languages are defining A as 10.

Comment: @nicael Yes, that's true.  I claim this answer is different because `bc` is not a golfing language.  It is in fact a [Posix-defined language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_(programming_language)) available by default on just about any standard *nix system you can find.

Answer (score 50):

## Fishing, score <s>7,958,661,109,946,400,884,391,936</s> 1,208,925,819,614,629,174,706,176

Is this the highest non-trivial-looking score ever in a minimization challenge? (Even though it has been golfed by 84.8%)

```
v+CCCCCCCCCC
  `32`nSSSSP
```

---

Explanation

```
v              Sets the casting direction to down
 +             Increments the casting distance by 1
  CCCCCCCCCC   Casts the rod

`32`         Pushes a string "32" to the stack
    n        Converts the stack from a string to an integer
     SSSS    Repeated squaring of the stack
         P   Prints the stack
```

The number is `32^16` and has 25 digits. The code is 24 bytes long. The previous answer was `6^32`.

Comment: Brought a tear to my eye. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: It will probably still beat Java... Hopefully.

Comment: Well, it beats C#...

Comment: Why 6 and not 9?

Comment: @immibis The goal of the challenge is to minimize the score, so it's not just minimizing bytes; putting 9 before would have increased my score unnecessarily.

Comment: But the number needs to have MORE digits than the size of the code.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Corrected.

Comment: Link to this language?

Answer (score 40):

## MATLAB, 1,000,000,000 (10<sup>9</sup>)

Also works with **Octave**

```
disp(1e9)
```

Never going to beat the esolangs, but just for fun, this is the smallest MATLAB/Octave will be able to do, so thought I would post it anyway.

Comment: The esolang answers, while valid, are kinda boring. Glad to see one that isn't!

Comment: perl `say 1e9` is slightly shorter, if you want to improve your golf score. (Though it's nowhere near the smaller integer for which this approach works...)

Comment: @derobert True. 1e1 would satisfy the problem statement and give a score of 10 (the lower, the better) (Assuming a char is 1 byte)

Comment: @dberm22 `10` (2 characters) is not longer than `1e1` (3 characters)

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Ahh, I read it as the magnitude of the printed number has to be larger than the bytecount, not the number of digits in the printed number. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Wouldn't `disp 1e8` work? I can't test at the moment but I don't recall MATLAB requiring parentheses for `disp`. **Edit** Oh nevermind, that just prints it as a string.

Answer (score 30):

## TI-84 BASIC, 120

```
5!
```

`ᴇ2` would score better if not for the silly UTF-8 requirement. (It's only two bytes in the calculator's native tokenized encoding, but it's 4 in UTF-8...)

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something, but the string "E2" is only two bytes in UTF-8…

Comment: @JasperBryant-Greene `ᴇ` and `E` are not the same character. In TI-BASIC, `ᴇ`  is scientific notation and `E` is a variable.

Comment: Thanks :) I should have noticed that the character was subtly-smaller-than-full-height…

Comment: Wouldn't `3!` score better?

Comment: @dberm22 3! has only 1 digit, we need at least 3.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Ahh, I read it as the magnitude of the printed number has to be larger than the bytecount, not the number of digits in the printed number. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Can't `ᴇ2` count as two bytes since the calculator's encoding isn't UTF-8, like Jelly?

Comment: @NobodyNada This time the question specifically said to score in UTF8, for some reason.

Comment: Oops, I misread that to say "this rule applies if your code is in ASCII or UTF-8."

Answer (score 28):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), score 100100

Code:

```
d!!@
```

In a more readable form:

```
  d !
 ! @ .
  . .
```

The char value of `d` is 100. This will simply print the char value twice and terminates after.

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=IGQgIQohIEAgLgogLiAu&input=)

Comment: Cute! Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: More readable form? Really? xD

Answer (score 27):

### C#, score <s>10^72</s> <s>10^70</s> <s>10^64</s> 10^63

```
class A{static void Main(){System.Console.Write($"1{0:D63}");}}
```

That's 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000. I guess that I tried...

Comment: Stunning, really.

Comment: Wouldn't `Write(new string('1',70))` be better?

Comment: You can write it out as a double rather than a string, which shortens it to 10^56 : `class A{static void Main(){System.Console.Write(1e56);}}`

Comment: @goric That just outputs `1E+56`.

Answer (score 20):

### JavaScript, score 100,000,000,000 (or 1*10<sup>11</sup>)

```js
alert(1e11)
```

This is if using alert. Though you can get 100 000 000 times lesser score if using console:

```
1e3
```

[image]

Score 1000 as you can see, I'm not sure it counts using the console though.

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't count!

Comment: @Arandur I'm guessing "I'm not sure it counts" refers to the lower score of 1000, since that requires using the console as a REPL, rather than being a full program.

Comment: @tri exactly, made a clarification.

Comment: +1 for alert, I would not allow the automatic console output

Answer (score 19):

## [PlatyPar](https://github.com/cyoce/PlatyPar), 59

```
#
```

`#` starts a numeric base-60 literal, and since no digits are found, it ends up as `59`. This started as a happy accident, but since I have already [ab]used this bug in [another answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66729/41042), I kept it.

[Try it online](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/PlatyPar/master/page.html?code=%23)!

Here's another approach, my take on the boring way that everyone and their grandmother used for this challenge.

## [PlatyPar](https://github.com/cyoce/PlatyPar), 100000000 (9 digits)

```
'18Md0+;
```

Explanation

```
'1        ## push "1" (a string) to the stack
  8Md  ;  ## repeat 8 times
     0+    ## add a 0
          ## [implicitly] print the result
```

[Try it online](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/PlatyPar/master/page.html?code=%2718Md0+%3B)!

Answer (score 17):

## C, 1000000000000000000000000000  (28 digits)

```c
main(){printf("1%027d",0);}
```

Similar to my C++ answer, without the `#include <stdio.h>`
(Ignore the warning about missing declaration of `printf`. Thanks @Dennis)

Newline would require an additional 2 bytes, using format `1%029d\n`

Answer (score 16):

## [Brainf**k](http://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/bf/), 11111111111111111111111111111111111 (~1e34)

And another reduction:

```
+++++++[>+++++++>+<<-]>>[<.....>-]
```

Which gives 35 consecutive 1's, or approximately 1e34.

---

A bit smaller still

```
++++++++[>++++++>+<<-]>+>+[<....>-]
```

Gives 36 1's which is a number about 11% larger than 1e35.

---

Thanks to @Martin Büttner for knocking off a couple of characters reducing the total output by a factor of 100 with this code (yields 1e36):

```
++++++[>++++++++>++<<-]>+.->[<...>-]
```

---

My old code (yields 1+e38):

```
++++++++[>++++++>++<<-]>+.->+++[<..>-]
```

I've been experimenting with esolangs out of boredom. This is the best I could do in BF. I wonder if it is possible to make it smaller?

You can try it online [here](http://esoteric.sange.fi/brainfuck/impl/interp/i.html).

Comment: I wrote a shorter answer, from scratch: [link](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68177/3852)

Comment: @Mauris impressive!

Answer (score 14):

### [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/), score 10

```
A
```

As shows the score, prints 10.

Comment: This is not code golf;the goal is to print the smallest number, your score is 10.

Comment: @ppp "The number must be longer in bytes than the program -- have more digits than the code has characters" - OP's just edited.

Comment: You have not misunderstood; if the Japt program `A` prints 10, then this is a valid program with a score of 10.

Comment: Woohoo, my language is tied for <s>first</s> second place! *glares at Retina*

Comment: Any reason for downvote?

Comment: I think the shortest program that doesn't use a variable is `#d`, scoring 100. With no byte literals, it would be `8s2`, scoring 1000.

Comment: Oh, `5l` scores 120.

Comment: Also works in [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/) for a score of ten.

Answer (score 13):

### Python 2, 101010101010

```
print'10'*6
```

Answer (score 10):

### PHP, score 10,000,000

```
<?=1e7;
```

This prints 10000000 as can be seen [there](http://justachat.freevar.com/test.php).

Comment: Since the OP asked for the smallest integer, why did you pick an exponent of seven?  Does it print without commas?

Comment: @WGroleau it does print without any commas, http://justachat.freevar.com/test.php

Answer (score 10):

## Brainfuck, 3333333333333333333333333 (25 threes)

This is written "from scratch" so I think it's okay to post a separate answer:

```
-[>+>+<<-----]>-[-->.<]
```

23 bytes long.

Comment: I was considering a bf solution, are there any current interpreters that only output as numbers?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala this outputs 51 (the ASCII code for `"3"`) 25 times.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt what Im saying is that there might exist a bf interpreter that doesn't input as ascii and only does integer output, thus (-.) would output 255.

Answer (score 9):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), score 10,000,000

```
1!!!!>@
```

It might be possible to bring this down by one order of magnitude, but I can't find anything right now.

The first `1!!!!` prints `1000`. Then `>` shifts the source code to

```
@1!!!!>
```

which avoids early termination. Then the IP hits a dead end and turns around. Now `!!!!` prints four more zeroes and `@` terminates the program.

[Try it online.](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=MSEhISEKQA&input=)

Answer (score 9):

## [DC](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Dc), 10000

4 chars program:

```
I4^f
```

5 digits output:

```
$ dc<<<'I4^f'
10000
```

Comment: +1.  Yep, I think that's optimal in dc.  Unusually [bc is shorter](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67992/11259).

Comment: I thought I was doing well with `6d^p` (yielding 46656), but you have that beat - well done!

Answer (score 9):

## [Samau](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Samau), 42

```
A
```

`A` pushes the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything onto the stack. Then the top of the stack is automatically printed.

Comment: I think something is wrong with your commit messages :P

Comment: @Doorknob冰 I don't know how to write commit messages, so I just use random emojis.

Comment: Ok, here's the real question: what does `Q` push?

Answer (score 8):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), 7! = 5040

```
7FN
```

Outputs 5040.

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=N0ZO&input=)

Comment: Why not `3FN` outputting `6`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor The number has to be greater in length, not greater in magnitude.

Answer (score 8):

## C, 11111111111111111111111111111111111 (35 ones)

```
main(c){while(c++<36)putchar(49);}
```

Maybe there's a shorter way. The lack of a simple way to print big numbers in C makes it tricky.

Answer (score 7):

### Python 2, 107918163081

```
print 69**6
```

Comment: You can remove the space between `print` and the `2`.

Comment: @Bakuriu No you can't

Comment: `69**6` is only `107918163081`.

Comment: Interstingly enough, this also works in Perl.

Comment: Technically, you can remove the space by replacing it with a `+`.

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, score 10

```
A
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=QQ&input=)

Comment: Why not `Y`, score 2?

Comment: Because `2` is only one character, so it isn't longer than the source code.

Answer (score 7):

## Java, 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 (81 ones)

```
interface A{static void main(String[]a){for(A i:new A[81])System.out.print(1);}}
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've underlined the part that is actually "variable" here; everything else is absolutely necessary for a working Java program.

Presumably this is shorter than mucking around with Java's `BigInteger`.

Comment: *Presumably ...* - perhaps `System.out.print(BigInteger.TEN.pow(10));` - is that one character less? Sorry - nowhere near big enough - and `.pow(10).pow(10)` is longer.

Comment: You can replace `interface` with `class`.

Comment: But then `main` would need to be `public`.

Comment: you can shave off 2 characters by doing this for the for loop: for(A a:new A[81])

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Would `.pow(100)` not work for some reason?

Comment: Why is it an interface??

Comment: Read the comment four comments above yours...

Answer (score 7):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 100100

```
@'dOu
```

Cubix is a 2-dimensional, stack-based esolang. Cubix is different from other 2D langs in that the source code is wrapped around the outside of a cube.

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=QCdkT3U=&input=&speed=3)

### Explanation

The first thing the interpreter does is figure out the smallest cube that the code will fit onto. In this case, the edge-length is 1. Then the code is padded with no-ops `.` until all six sides are filled. Whitespace is removed before processing, so this code is identical to the above:

```
  @
' d O u
  .
```

Now the code is run. The IP (instruction pointer) starts out on the far left face, pointing east.

The first char the IP encounters is `'`, which pushes the next byte onto the stack; this byte is `d`, or `100`. Next is `O`, which outputs the top item (100) as an integer.

Then the IP hits `u`, which turns it to the right, moves it forward, then turns it again. It switches to the bottom face pointing north, then rotates to the east. This wraps it to the `O` again, outputting 100, then up to `@` which terminates the program.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), score 120

```
5!
```

Calculates the factorial of 5. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=NSE&input=)

Comment: It specifies that the text encoding should be UTF-8 - is that followed here?

Comment: I was going to say -- this might be the first esolang that actually *can't* trivially answer this question.

Comment: @FlagAsSpam I missed that unusual rule. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 1000

```
1e3
```

*Note: [latest GitHub commit](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/commit/77a5eba228ccedec8ac0d58d0f1842aba03858cc) of the compiler works on Octave as well as on Matlab.*

This interprets the number in scientific notation, and implicitly prints it, thus producing the output

> 1000

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, 1000000000

```
print 1e9
```

Straightforward.

Comment: Can't you reduce your score by using `say`?

Comment: That would require enabling the `-E` flag, I suppose. I'm not sure how to count that, in this challenge.

Comment: Since ["`-M5.010`, when needed, is free,"](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/274/31388) you shouldn't have to count it at all.

Answer (score 6):

### C++, 1e46

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){printf("1%046d",0);}
```

Newline would require an additional 2 bytes, using format "1%048d\n"

Comment: I don't think C++ allows you to omit the return type of `main()`.  OTOH, this would make a good C answer...

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` => `#include<stdio.h>` or even `#include<cstdio>`

Answer (score 5):

## O, 10

```
A
```

Apparently the score is the number we print!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), score 10

Code

```
T
```

Explanation:

```
T         # Puts 10 onto the stack
          # Implicit, print the last item of the stack
```

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, score 87,178,291,200

```
Print[14!]
```

This solution is not helped by the fact that it takes 6 characters to print anything.

Comment: Why do you want to use `Print` though? Raw operations are valid programs in Mathematica ([answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68027/36328))

Comment: @MarchHo the fact that you got away with it in the past does not mean it's generally legitimate to assume a REPL environment. ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I don't get your point. It manifestly does **not** "take 6 characters to print anything" for this question in Mathematica. I don't see where REPL environments come into play here.

Comment: @MarchHo if you run `14!` from a script file, it will not print anything. It only prints something when typed into a notebook, which is a REPL environment.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I just tested in Mathematica 10, `Get["C:\\test.txt"]` containing the string `15!` prints the expected output. Did I misinterpret what you said?

Comment: @MarchHo, try running `MathematicaScript -script C:\test.txt`.

Comment: @MarchHo what LegionMammal said. You are still invoking the code from a notebook. Mathematica code can be run as an actual script without a notebook environment just like any other programming language.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I was about to post in Meta, but [someone beat me to it](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7842/when-is-code-that-requires-a-repl-acceptable)

Comment: @MarchHo See my comment on your answer.

Comment: We should create a golfing version of Mathematica. With one- or two-byte abbreviated commands and the massive Wolfram Language command set, it would do well in many of these contests.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I love that name, I was assuming "MMA" but yours is better. Don't try to bite off the whole spec in one go -- maybe Mthmtca 0.1 can have shortened command names plus automatic universal right parenthesis (both relatively easy to implement), and leave everything else for version 0.2.

Comment: @MichaelStern The repository can be found [here](https://github.com/LegionMammal978/Mthmtca).

Comment: @LegionMammal978 yessir

Comment: @MichaelStern Give me a few minutes to test some things.

Comment: `Echo[13!]` works

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg That prints a leading `>>`.

Answer (score 5):

### [Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/mbuettner/brian-chuck), 11,111,111,111,111 (≈ 1.1e13)

```
?1<SO>{?
#{>.>-?
```

Here, `<SO>` stands for the "shift out" control character with character code 0x0E.

[Try it online.](http://brian-chuck.tryitonline.net/#code=PzEOez8KI3s-Lj4tPw&input=)

That's all my language covered then. :)

#### Explanation

The `1` in Brian's code (first line) is used for printing. Then `<SO>` is used as a counter variable. The rest is just a simple loop setup which prints that `1` while decrementing the `<SO>` down to zero.

Answer (score 5):

## Marbelous, 100000000000000000000000 (24 digits)

Previously <s>28</s>, <s>26</s> digits

```
@1
-- 10 '0
=0 @1
!! \\ /\ '1
```

All the spaces are superfluous. Outputs 1 then 0 repeatedly while counting down in parallel. Layout and counter tweaked to produce the desired amount of output for a 23-byte program.

Answer (score 5):

## TeaScript, 10 points

```
e
```

The `e` variable is preinitialized to 10

[Try it online](http://vihan.org/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22e%22&inputs=%5B%22%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:false,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false%7D)

Comment: Isn't that confusing, given that e is another number?

Comment: @Cyoce true but variable `Me` is e so both are usable

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 1679616

```
p 6**8
```

Computes 6<sup>8</sup>.

Answer (score 5):

### QBasic, 15625

```
?5^6
```

`?` auto-magically gets converted to `PRINT`, 5 to the power of 6 yields the most convenient number of more than 4 bytes.

Comment: QBasic automagically converts your code to `PRINT 5 ^ 6` (which is 11 bytes) _before_ it is run. I'm not counting the 2 bytes for the newline because that would be mean but strictly speaking even the empty QBasic program has two bytes...

Comment: @CJDennis If I save this in a `.BAS` file and ask `QBasic.exe` to `/run` that, it runs.

Answer (score 5):

## Java, 12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546 (~10<sup>82</sup>)

Curent version:

```
interface N{static void main(String[]a){for(int i=0;i<46;)System.out.print(++i);}}
```

Previous version [score floor(10<sup>84</sup>/9)=111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111]:

```
interface N{static void main(String[]a){for(int i=0;i<84;i++)System.out.print(1);}}
```

Original version (score 10<sup>93</sup>):

```
interface N{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(java.math.BigInteger.TEN.pow(93));}}
```

Answer (score 5):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 10560

```
'*n`
```

[Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=JypuYA&input=)

```
'*n`'         Push chars to stack, giving [42 110 96]
     *        Multiply, giving [42 10560]
      n       Output 10560 as number
       `      Unrecognised char, so the program outputs with an error
```

Unfortunately, out of all chars smaller than `` ` `` which give a 5-digit output, none of `[\]^_` work since they are valid instructions which don't cause the termination we require.

Answer (score 5):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 1001101

```
>1!:
@
```

As [Martin predicted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67947/21487), one order of magnitude lower is possible! [Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=PjEhOgpA&input=)

I'm not going to go into full details as to how Labyrinth works, but this trace should give a rough idea as to what's going on anyway:

```
Inst   Detail                                    Stack            Output
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>      Rotate row 0 right                        []

[Board update]
:>1!
@

1      * 10 + 1                                  [1]
!      Output                                    []               1
1      * 10 + 1                                  [1]
>      Rotate row 1 right                        []

[Board update]
:>1!
 @

:      Dup                                       [0 0]
>      Rotate row 0 right                        [0]

[Board update]
!:>1
 @

1      * 10 + 1                                  [1]
>      Rotate row 1 right                        []

[Board update]
!:>1
  @

:      Dup                                       [0 0]
!      Output                                    [0]              0
:      Dup                                       [0 0]
>      Rotate row 0 right                        [0]

[Board update]
1!:>
  @

:      Dup                                       [0 0]
!      Output                                    [0]              0
1      * 10 + 1                                  [1]
!      Output                                    []               1
:      Dup                                       [0 0]
>      Rotate row 0 right                        [0]

[Board update]
>1!:
  @

1      * 10 + 1                                  [1]
!      Output                                    []               1
:      Dup                                       [0 0]
!      Output                                    [0]              0
1      * 10 + 1                                  [1]
>      Rotate row 1 right                        []

[Board update]
>1!:
   @

1      * 10 + 1                                  [1]
!      Output                                    []               1
:      Dup                                       [0 0]
@      Halt
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Come Here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Come_Here), floor(10<sup>42</sup>/9)

```
0CALL42cCOME FROM SGNcCALLc-1c1TELL49NEXT
```

Ungolfed:

```
0 NOTE It is illegal to "COME FROM" a nonexistant label.
CALL 42 c NOTE c=42
COME FROM SGN c NOTE If c>0, come back here after next reaching label 1
CALL c-1 c NOTE decrement c
1 TELL 49 NEXT NOTE I really don't understand why the parser requires NEXT here, but it does
```

Answer (score 5):

## [NTFJ](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/NTFJ), 111111111111111111111111111111 (30 ones)

Code:

```
#(#~~~#@::::::)$::::*****(~#^
```

### Explanation

One the first run through we push six 49s (ASCII value for one) to set up for the loop this only runs the first time because `#` is used to enter the loop.  On all subsequent runs the `#` is skipped and thus the loop is skipped as well.

After that as well as with all future runs we pop a value `$` which for the first run is a 49 but for all subsequent runs is the zero used to skip the loop.  We then duplicate the TOS four times and output five times decreasing the total by one.  If the TOS is zero (i.e. not 49) we end the program otherwise we jump back to the first instruction immediately skipping to back to four duplications.

This outputs 30 ones and has a length of 29.

### Additional solution

I thought since Conor O'Brien forgot about the `:` operator I'd do a solution without it to be fair to him.

```
#(##################~)~##~~~#@*~~##~~~~@*~~##~~~~@*$(~#^
```

This prints

```
100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100
```

I was going to make an explanation for this but I forgot how it works.

Comment: Wow, I like the alternative solution. Fantastic!

Answer (score 4):

## GolfScript, 3125

```
5.?
```

Computes 5<sup>5</sup>.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 1,000,000,000

Even lower than my [other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67921/what-is-the-smallest-positive-base-10-integer-that-can-be-printed-by-a-program-s/67990#67990) (but includes a trailing zero, which I did not count towards the score). Similar to the Matlab/Octave solution.

```
print 1e9
```

Comment: 'Lowest integer' - the .0 at the end stops this from being valid.

Comment: @muddyfish: The integers are members of the set of all real numbers.  Representing an integer as a decimal string doesn't stop it from being an exact integer.  I won't fully parse with a function that only parses C integral types (like `strtol`), but the question asked for an integer, not an `int`.

Comment: I have to agree that although it does not look like an integer, it still satisfies all the mathematical properties of an integer.

Answer (score 4):

#### Windows PowerShell, 1000

```
1e3
```

Another methods to achieve something similar, though not as small, may be

```
1KB   # 1024
```

Answer (score 4):

## Excel & LibreOffice Calc – 10000

```
=1e4
```

Save as `challenge.csv`, then open in Excel or Calc. Usually just double-clicking will do.

Comment: "I.e. the code must be shorter than the number of digits in the resulting number"

Comment: ```=1e4``` would do for 10000.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 327228837632722883924195568 (28 digits)

```
main(){printf("%u%u%u");}
```

Undefined behavior is awesome!!! This solution probably doesn't count due to UB, but I just wanted to put the idea out there.

[Using Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8c028becf505d41), I get that output every time.

Answer (score 4):

## Vim, 11111

```
5i1␛
```

Works by inserting the character `1` five times. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfkl@anKGQlpmTqldSUcJVlJqYoqBbpKCboqCkpOCsYGOj4Orv9t800/DRhNn/gUwuZ1sllWpnfX0gX19FPSZVvVaJqywzV0G3VMHP389VQUk7L78oNzFHQcVZSUFdu7xQHW66gpqdgn5Kapl@XmlODldyYglc5j8A)

Answer (score 4):

## Flurry, score 1

The empty program returns the identity function `λa. a` = `λab. a b`, which is the Church numeral representation of 1. The interpreter recognizes and prints it as such:

```
$ ./Flurry -nin -c ''
1
```

It takes the interpreter \$O(n)\$ time to convert from integer to decimal in order to print it, so any other answer would probably need to use character IO if it wanted to execute in reasonable time.

Answer (score 4):

## [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 100010001000100010001000 (~1e23)

Without any basic math support, just text manipulation, the easiest solution I found was to duplicate some starting number, 1000 in this case. Printing is implicit at the end of the script, 22 bytes in length.

```sed
s:$:1000:
s:.*:&&&&&&:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v9hKxcrQwMDAiqvYSk/LSg0MrP7/BwA)

I believe this is the first sed answer to this question. It's also my first after a long break from code golf :)

Comment: [this](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v9hKxcoACKy4iq30rAwNwOz0//8B) is the same size, but produces a slightly smaller number

Comment: @JoKing Nice. Do you want to post it separately or should I include it in my answer?

Comment: Feel free to update your answer. I don't actually know that much sed

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge 98 - 10000000000:

```
a8k:8k*.@
```

or:

```
a8k:8k*.q
```

The number printed has twelve didgits and the program is eleven bytes long.

Answer (score 3):

## Microscript/Microscript II, 100

```
2E
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 1001129150390625

```
main=print$75^8
```

Probably minimal. I can't think of a shorter way to make a large integer and print it than exponentiation (`^`); you need at least `main=print$`. Of all choices for base and exponent, `75^8` was the lowest number longer than the code.

EDIT: Thanks, Neil!

Comment: We still have no topic on meta that defines the minimum requirements for a full program. Maybe we can use the `-e` option of `ghc` and go with `ghc -e "4^5"` for a 3 byte program with a score of 1024.

Comment: Actually `75^8` is only `1001129150390625`.

Answer (score 3):

## C++, 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 (60 ones)

```
#include<cstdio>
int main(int c){while(c++<61)putchar(49);}
```

Translation of my C answer.

Comment: You could get 59 nines with `int main(int c){while(c-->-putchar(57);)}` for the second line. The same result could be get with a `for` instead and adding 2 `;`.

Comment: You should post that yourself, it's quite clever!

Answer (score 3):

### Java, 10^72

```java
interface A{static void main(String[]a){System.out.printf("1%072d",0);}}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge ([quirkster implementation](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html)), 123648

```
"**.@
```

Pushes the string `**.@` onto the stack, wraps around, exits string mode, and executes it, multiplying the ASCII values of the last three characters and outputting the result as an integer.

Edit: Only works if the playfield width is considered to be implicitly set to the maximum line width, not right-padded to a default size. Thanks to James Holderness for the catch.

Answer (score 3):

## R - 134217728

```
cat(8^9)
```

I doubt it can be make any shorter having to use `cat` function. Pretty boring, though.

Edit: Improved thanks to [Christian Sievers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56725/christian-sievers)

Comment: My version answers with "1e+09", and anyway, why not 8^9?

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](http://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11111111

```
Ｆ⁸1
```

[Try it online!](http://charcoal.tryitonline.net/#code=77ym4oG4MQ)

[`for(8)Print('1')`](http://charcoal.tryitonline.net#code=Zm9yKDgpUHJpbnQoJzEnKQ&args=LXY).

Charcoal could have done better (1111 score) if source was measured in Charcoal bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), score 111111111111111111111111111111111111 (<s>39</s> 36 ones)

```
/<<<<<%<@<<<?<<</
?+-*66<:<+1$<*77/
```

-111100000000000000000000000000000000000 score (-4 ones) thanks to *@JoKing*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/X98GBFRtHICkPRDrc9lr62qZmdlY2WgbqthomZvr////X9cRAA) or [verify that it's deterministic](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/X98GBFRtHICkPRDrc9lr62qZmdlY2WgbqthomZvr////X9fxv24YAA).

#### Explanation:

**Explanation of the language in general:**

Lost is a 2D path-walking language. Most 2D path-walking languages start at the top-left position and travel towards the right by default. Lost is unique however, in that ***both the start position AND starting direction it travels in is completely random***. So making the program deterministic, meaning it will have the same output regardless of where it starts or travels, can be quite tricky.

A Lost program of 2 rows and 5 characters per row can have 40 possible program flows. It can start on any one of the 10 characters in the program, and it can start traveling up/north, down/south, left/west, or right/east.

In Lost you therefore want to lead everything to a starting position, so it'll follow the designed path you want it to. In addition, you'll usually have to clean the stack when it starts somewhere in the middle.

**Explanation of the program:**

`?` will pop the top item of the stack, and will skip the next character if it is NOT a 0. Because of this, the stack will be emptied completely due to the leading characters of both lines while traveling downwards. So the `?` pops values, and we'll ignore the `/`, until the stack is empty. At this point, an implicitly pushed 0 is used for the `?`, and the `/` is no longer skipped.

Another important fact is that in a Lost program, an `@` will terminate the program, but only when the safety is 'off'. When the program starts, the safety is always 'on' by default, otherwise a program flow starting at the exit character `@` would immediately terminate without doing anything. The `%` will turn this safety 'off', so when we now encounter an `@` the program will terminate (if the safety is still 'on', the `@` will be a no-op instead).

As for the program flow: all arrows and `/` reflects will lead the path towards the `<` between the `%` and `@`.

From there, the program flow will:

- `<`: Travel left/west
- `%`: Turn the safety 'off' (so if we would now encounter the `@`, the program will stop)
- `<<<<<`: Continue traveling left/west
- `/`: Reflect to a downwards/south direction
- `?`: Pop the top value of the stack, and if it's NOT 0, skip the next operand. As mentioned earlier, this `?/` will clean the entire stack in case we started somewhere in between, after which an implicit pushed `0` will allow us to go to the next step:
- `/` (first row; first column): Reflect to a left/west direction
- `/` (first row; last column): Reflect to a downwards/south direction
- `/` (second row; last column): Reflect to a left/west direction

  - `77*`: Push 49 (push 7; push 7; pop and multiply the top two values)
  - `<`: Continue traveling left/west
  - `$`: Swap the top two values. If the stack only contains a single value, it will implicitly use a `0` to swap.
  - `1+`: Add one to this counter-value
  - `<`: Continue traveling left/west
  - `:`: Duplicate the top of the stack
  - `<`: And once again, continue traveling left/west
  - `66*`: Push 36 (push 6; push 6; pop and multiply the top two values)
  - `-+`: Subtract it from the duplicated counter-value
  - `?`: Pop, and if this is NOT 0, skip the next operand. The first iteration this will be `-36`, thus NOT 0, so it will skip the `/` when it wraps around to the other side and do the same again starting at `77*`. This will continue until the counter-value has become `0`, after which the mirror `/` is not skipped.
- `/` (second row; last column): In that case, it will reflect downwards/south
- `/` (first row; last column): Reflect to a left/west direction again
- `<<<`: Continue traveling left/west
- `?`: Pop the top value on the stack (the duplicated counter-value)
- `<<<`: Continue traveling left/west
- `@`: Terminate the program if the safety is 'off' (which it is at this point). After which all the values on the stack will be output implicitly. Using the `-A` program argument flag, these code-points (the `49`s) will be output as a string of characters (`'1'`s) instead without delimiter. Without this flag, it would output the `49`s as numbers with space delimiters; so due to those implicit space delimiters, we can't simply push `1`s and remove the `-A` flag.

Comment: I was able to shorten the program but I can't get 38, 1s. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v0zVxkHDBg647O3igKSdubmWipWZmZautn2cofb///91Hf/rhgEA "Lost – Try It Online")

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter Oh, I initially had the reversed. I was able to make it shorter, but couldn't figure out how to have less than 39 1s. Unfortunately `37` is a prime number, and `38`/`39` are only divisible by the pairs `[[1,38],[2,19]]` and `[[1,39],[3,13]]` respectively, which makes them annoying to work with.

Comment: @JoKing Very nice approach with the reflects! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 1 byte

```
t
```

Outputs `10`.

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJ0IiwiIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Answer (score 2):

## AppleScript, 10^3

```
1e3
```

Implicit output? :o

Answer (score 2):

## gs2, 10

```
→
```

A single byte of CP437. Prints `10`. [Try it here!](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=4oaS&input=)

Comment: OP said UTF-8 (I disagree with the rules, but OP might not change them.)

Comment: This answer is invalid because this is 2 bytes in UTF-8, which is the encoding specified in the challenge.

Comment: @Mego CP437 and UTF-8 are compatible in the first 128 bytes. This is just a dingbat that represents the actual control character.

Comment: Oh, whoops, I missed the fact that it was in the lower half. I should know better, considering how much I've worked with CP437 for Seriously...

Answer (score 2):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse15), 10101010

`k` is 10, but `!` printing costs a byte, so this is the only way.

```
kkkk(!)
```

Exits with an error, if run interactively.

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge-93, 101010101010

```
6<_@#:-1.+4
```

I can't immediately think of anything shorter, but I think this is pretty good.

**EDIT**: got it from 161616161616 to 101010101010.

Comment: [100000000](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/PyVFSctKS8/h/38A "Befunge-93 – Try It Online")

Comment: @JamesHolderness, [why not just one d?](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/P0VJy0pLz@H/fwA)

Comment: @JoKing I'm an idiot! No idea how I missed that. Can also do [one c](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/P1lJy0pLz@H/fwA "Befunge-93 – Try It Online") for a smaller number.

Answer (score 2):

## Commodore Basic, 1000000

```
1?1E6
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, score 120

```
5!
```

Contrary to the assertion in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67948/36328), you don't need `Print` to print something in Mathematica. Mathematical operations like exponentiation and factorials are supported by default.

Comment: why did you change your score from 120 to 1024?

Comment: @Sparr It was a  mistake, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @glenn I was under the impression the length of the number must be longer than the program itself.

Comment: "Write a *full* program (not just a function)"; this isn't a full program, it's a REPL snippet.

Comment: I think this would be a valid TI-BASIC answer too.

Answer (score 2):

## F#, 10000000000000000000

Here's a pretty clever trick:

```
printf"%o"(1L<<<57)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pure bash, 1125899906842624 (2<sup>50</sup>, 16 digits).

```
echo $((1<<50))
```

This is the best *pure* bash I've come up with, not depending on any special conditions or using external commands.

**Bash + POSIX, 100000000: (10<sup>8</sup>, 9 digits)**

```
bc<<<A^8   # bc with a here-string script that evaluates 10^8
```

Thanks to Digital Trauma's answer for bringing up `bc` and the fact that it accepts hex digits even with the default ibase=10.  Glenn beat me to actually posting the `bc`-based answer, but I'll leave it in my answer as well for completeness.

---

I'm an infrequent golfer, so IDK if there are standard assumptions that rule this out, to avoid needing overly pedantic rules in every question:

### Bash + rule-bending: 10737418240 (5 * 2<sup>31</sup>, 11 digits)

The question doesn't appear to rule out the the long number being be part of a longer string (e.g. part of an error message):

```
$((5<<31))          # prints "bash: 10737418240: command not found"
```

---

#### Bash assuming a 5-digit PID: a 10-digit number (PID repeated twice)

```
echo $$$$       # depends on the shell's current PID being a 5-digit number
```

Or repeating 3 times to still work with a 4-digit PID: a 12 or 15 digit number.  (e.g. 573057305730: The shell's PID repeated 3 times).

```
echo $$$$$$     # depends on the shell's current PID being a 4-digit number
```

---

#### test framework for the number-generating expression:

```
e='$((5<<31))'; eval decimal=$e;  echo "$decimal: srclen=${#e}  digits=${#decimal}"
```

test framework for whole commands (works with methods other than the error-message hack.)

```
e='bc<<<A^8'; eval decimal=\"\$\($e\)\";  echo "$decimal: srclen=${#e}  digits=${#decimal}"
```

up-arrow and edit `e` to try different numbers.

---

Ideas that didn't work:  (for readability, not fully golfed and in a `(subshell)` to avoid breaking your interactive shell when testing.)

```
(set {1..9}; IFS=; echo "$*" )   # $* in double quotes joins with no separator if IFS is null.  Too much setup overhead
```

You could play silly tricks to get `$0` to contain a long number, but then you'd have to count the whole `bash -c 'echo $0' $((10**7))` as part of the program.

Answer (score 2):

### [Self-modifying Brainf***](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Self-modifying_Brainfuck), 111,000,000,000,000 (1.11e14)

`_` represents a null byte `\x00`. Prints each digit 3 times. I'm also fairly certain this is minimal. Interleaving digits with code is longer. There are several shorter solutions where the number is of *equal* length, but not longer.

```
<[...<]_00001
```

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 111111

```
"1"*6
```

If the newline counts, then `"1"*5` prints `11111\n`.

Answer (score 2):

## ><> (fish), 1000010000

```
a:*:*:nn;
```

explaination:

duplicates and multiplies 10 to get to two 10000's then prints both, being ten total characters long, one more than the program character length

Comment: First reaction : meh, there must be something better, let's try using a loop, using ascii values as integer or even exiting with an error ! 1 hour later : <strike>damn you</strike> well done torcado !

Comment: @Aaron haha yeah I also thought there was for sure a shorter way to do this but this is the best I could get. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## marioLANG, 700666666005555550044444400333333002222220011111100 (51 digits for 49 bytes)

still no marioLANG anwser? well here's one,

[**Try it online**](http://mariolang.tryitonline.net/#code=KworCisKKworCishOjo6Ojo6PAorIz09PT09PSIKOj4pOjooLVshCj0iPT09PT09Iw&input=)

```
+
+
+
+
+
+!::::::<
+#======"
:>)::(-[!
="======#
```

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 15625

```
=5^6
```

equals 15625

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 1000000000

A simple program in a simple language. I have two answers depending on wether the python shell is permitted or not.

If it isn't, then:

```
print 1e9
```

Which is 9 bytes and outputs `1000000000`, 10 bytes.

If it is, then:

```
1e3
```

Which is 3 bytes and outputs `1000`, 4 bytes.

These ignore the `.0` printed on the end of these numbers since the method returns a float and the question asks for an int.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 1844674407370955161518446744073709551615 (40 digits)

```
main(){printf("%lu%1$lu",-1ul);}
```

Certainly not winning, but it's a fun challenge and this is a fun answer.

How it works:

- The `printf` format specifier `%lu` prints a `long unsigned` integer.
- The `printf` format specifier `%1$lu` prints the first `long unsigned` integer in `printf`'s argument list.
- `-1ul` in `printf`'s argument list is `-1` cast to an `unsigned long`. Since the value is negative and the integer is unsigned, it turns into the maximum value an `unsigned long` can hold.

Comment: Actually, `-1ul` is an unsigned long value 1, negated.  `(unsigned long)-1` would be `-1` cast to an `unsigned long`.  BTW, you could reduce the score a little by using `-9ul`.

Answer (score 2):

### Whitespace, 11111111111111111111111111111111111111 (38 ones)

Visible representation:

```
SSTTSSTTSNNSSNSSSTNSNSTNSTTSSSSNSNTTN
```

What it does:

```
     push -38
loop:
     push 1
      dup
       pnum
      add
     dup
      jn loop
```

Surprisingly short for a whitespace program. Other considered approaches were pushing a big integer followed by a sequence of duplicate-multiply but this proved to be less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

## Cubically, score <s>836,308,545</s> <s>328,426,785</s> <s>45,454,545</s> 1,818

<sup>Knocked the score down by utilizing existing face values instead of wasting space messing with the notepad. Too bad I golfed it before the revision history kicked in :(</sup>

```
%22
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P9f1cjo//@vefm6yYnJGakA) Explanation:

- Functions are called strangely in Cubically. When the interpreter hits a function, it sets the internal "default function" to that function. Then, when it hits any integer, it calls the internal default function with that integer. So `R1` will call `R` with `1`, `R11` will call `R` with `1` twice, etc.
- `%22` prints the value of the front face (`18`) two times.

*Outdated:*

Fun fact! Due to how functions are called in Cubically, for each extra byte (`6` at the end) we add, we can multiply the output length. Example:

```
:5*6666%66
```

Prints `836308545836308545`. `:5*6666%666` prints `836308545836308545836308545`. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 123334567 (8 bytes)

```
00000000: 3cf6 30fe 3820 0176                      <.0.8 .v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBSMk9PMFIwN0lIVjC2MDBQMDM3NFLACGz0DPQsFvbL//wE)

Disassembly:

```
  inc a
  or '0'
  cmp '8'
  jr nz, ok
  halt
ok:
```

Runs as follows:

- A is incremented, then `or`'d by `'0'`, giving `'1'`.
- This is not `'8'`, so we jump past the `halt`.
- Code runs through many NOPs into putchar (`$8000`). **We print '1'.** Then we effectively `ret`urn: The PC is set to `(SP)` which is `$f63c`, the first word in memory (i.e. the first word of our code) – *we never pushed anything, so we're stack-underflowing into our own code, interpreting it as 16-bit addresses*. SP is incremented by 2, now `$0002`.
- PC runs through NOPs from `$f63c` to `$0000`, the start of our code. A is incremented to `'2'`.
- We jump past the `halt` again and run into `$8000`. **We print '2',** then jump to `$fe30` and SP is now `$0004`. We run from there into `$0000`, the start of our code again.
- We similarly **print '3'**, but the next return address we pop is `$2038`, which means the PC reaches `$8000` again before it reaches our code; so we **print '3'** again, then returning to `$7601` and thus **printing '3'** a third time; before finally returning to `$0000` where execution continues as normal. Now SP is `$000a`.
- Nothing is weird past here: the return address will always be `$0000` since `SP` is now pointing *after* our code. We count up **printing '4', '5', '6', '7'** until finally A = '8' and we `halt`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), <s>111111111 (8 bytes)</s> 11111111 (7 bytes)

```
00000000: 3676 6636 3b3e 31                        6vf6;>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBSMzczNFMzMjM0UjJOMUxWMDRVwALOyNDNrO8P//wE)

#### Disassembly

```
start:
  ld (hl), $76 ; 36 76 ; overwrite the 1st byte of program to `halt`
  ld h, (hl)   ; 66    ; h = $76; hl = $7600
  ld (hl), $3b ; 36 3b ; write `dec sp` to memory $7600
  ld a, $31    ; 3e 31 ; a = '1'
```

The main point is what happens after the program runs through the code. Every time before reaching `putchar`, the PC hits `dec sp` at `$7600`. This means each run of `putchar` increases SP by 1 instead of 2. So the return addresses become the following:

```
$7600 -> $7676 -> $3666 -> $3b36 -> $3e3b -> $313e -> $0031 -> $0000
```

Note that, when the return address is `$7676`, `dec sp` is skipped. So the ASCII 1 is printed 8 times in total.

---

### Previous solution, 111111111 (8 bytes)

```
00000000: 3e31 0609 ff10 fd76                      >1.....v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBSMU40NFQzMDCwV0tIMDRTSUszNFLACO0M9ECj7/x8A)

#### Disassembly

```
start:
  ld a,$31  ; 3e 31 ; a = '1'
  ld b,9    ; 06 09 ; b = 9
loop:
  rst $38   ; ff    ; equivalent to "call $8000" or "call putchar"
  djnz loop ; 10 fd ; b -= 1; if (b) goto loop
  halt      ; 76
```

Arguably less clever than [Lynn's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166964/78410) but still an improvement. This uses the instruction `djnz` which is similar to `dec b` then `jr nz, label`, but one byte shorter. If `b` is not touched before the loop, `b` starts with zero and the loop runs exactly 256 times.

Answer (score 2):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), 11109876543210

```
a->Out_a!12a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f8/UdfOv7QkPlHR0Cjx/38A)

Down from ~1e18 to ~1e14 thanks to [@Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
₀
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%80&inputs=&header=&footer=)

literal 10.

Comment: [Score 0, 0 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: @lyxal I asked in TNB, and apparently 0 isn't positive.

Comment: [score 1,  0 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJsIiwiIiwiIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Answer (score 2):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle) (-u), 3.134e144

```
1v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v
AB~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~ v~
  >^>^>^>^>^>^>^>v>+
^                ~^!1BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/9@wzA4Ncjk61dmhQIWyOi4FBbs4FFhmp80Vp4AG6uIUDZ2cnBz@//@vWwoA)
[See it online!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/BitCycle/?p=1sesesesesesesesesrABzezezezezezezezcszrc2enenenenenenenesetrnc9c7znb1B3a&f=1)
*The TiO has been truncated so that you can spend more time with your grandkids*
This program multiplies the amount of bits entering by 256, then converts them to `1`'s and adds it to the output. Each time this happens, a bit moves 1 space through the line of `B`'s. Once the bit reaches the `@`, the program terminates. The output can be expressed as: \$\sum_{n=1}^{60}256^n\$

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), 1.111<s>e29</s> e26

```
~~ v
 ^~
AB~
~0<~BBB@
!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/7@uTqGMSyGujsvRqY6rzsCmzsnJyYFL8f///wA)
[See it online!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/BitCycle/?p=z2csrcnzrABzrz0wzB3arb)
This is a similar concept to the first one, but it outputs in binary. Specifically, 27 `1`'s

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), 2.417e24

```
~~ v
 ^~
AB~
~0<~BBBB@
!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/7@uTqGMSyGujsvRqY6rzsCmzgkIHLgU//8HAA)
[See it online!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/BitCycle/?p=z2csrcnzrABzrz0wzB4arb)
The best of both worlds! This outputs a binary string of 81 `1`'s, which, in decimal, is \${{2}^{81}}-{1}\$

Comment: Just as some other answers manipulate a string which is then output, your second answer prints a string of binary digits that can be interpreted as a base-10 integer. I'd say it's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), <del>8.16e153</del> 1.25e146

7 digits removed thanks to Robin Ryder.

```
,.Ajax,.Puck,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Exeunt][Enter Ajax and Puck]Puck:If notyou cat.Open
heart.You be twice you.Be twice you nicer I?If solet usact I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY09DsIwDIV3TvEOUPkAXRBIHTKBxISqDsEY8VM5VeKo5fQh2Visz@99ltMyl9LR4e23js6ZP5XZ4Hq6sKg0GIdNsto0DmoS0VR4vaPZUxu9e0CDfUMGe6PTIrp7io9G1xrdBLa@WFB7Ov4t0AoRbl/PU5jFkJNvv6mUHw)

Output:

```
124816326412825651210242048409681921638432768655361310722621445242881048576209715241943048388608167772163355443267108864134217728268435456536870912
```

Doubles the integer in a loop until it overflows the 32 bit signed integer type.

Comment: [1.24e146](https://tio.run/##TY09CsMwDIWv8g4QdIAspYUMnlroVEIGV1HpT5CDLdP09K69ZRGf3vuE0rqU0tHx7beOLpk/ldngerqyqDQYh02y2jQOahLRVHid0eypjd49oMF@IYO90XkVxVN8NLrV6C6w74sFtafTboFWiHCHep7CIoacfPtNpfwB "Shakespeare Programming Language – Try It Online") by using `I` instead of `zero` and by overflowing one iteration earlier.

Answer (score 2):

## Pascal,  \$1 \! \cdot \! 10^{43}\$  or   1

See also [Free Pascal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168520/94076).
This is a *complete* `program` according to ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal”, though.
`Write(1E43:1:0)` prints (or ought to print) the value `10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.
The `:1` specifies the *minimum* width the output shall occupy.
The `:0` disables [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) and prints exactly `0` digits after the decimal point.
Since it doesn’t make sense to print the decimal point `.` if no digits follow, it also omits the `.` itself.
This behavior is an Extended Pascal extension (in ISO standard 7185 only *positive* `integer` values are accepted as format specifiers).

```pascal
program p(output);begin write(1E43:1:0)end.
```

Note the characteristics of the built-in data type `real` are **implementation-defined**.
`Write` in conjunction with `real` (such as `1E43`) always produces *rounded* output with respect to the last printed digit(s).
For instance, using *an* implementation of Pascal that internally uses IEEE 754 floating point numbers (depending on the precision) you may observe rounding errors.
This, however, is a circumstance *outside* of the realm of the programming language.
Sample:

```
9999999999999999999740000000000000000000000
```

*Mathematically* speaking the smallest positive integer value we can print in Pascal which has a longer printed length than the corresponding source code is \$1\$ (**positive one**).

```pascal
program p(output);begin write(1.0:42)end.
```

This will print (the casing of the letter `E` may vary):

```
 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000E+00
```

This is *a* representation of the value 1.
The value 1 is in the domain of ℤ, the set of integers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Candy](https://github.com/dale6john/candy), 10

```
N
```

push the number 10 onto the stack.  10 is useful since it's ascii for \n

Candy dumps the stack on exit.

Comment: BTW, your score is the number printed, not the length of the code.

Comment: @ETHproductions oh, should I have printed something like 10 (1 digit)?

Answer (score 1):

### Bash, 100000000 (9 digits)

```
bc<<<A^8
```

Solution by @Digital Trauma ported to bash.

Comment: crap, I took a break from my answer before coming back to finish tidying it up and post it, and you snuck in ahead of me >.<

Answer (score 1):

### [ResPlicate](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ResPlicate), score 111111111

```
2 9 0 49
```

I was thinking of all kinds of complicated ways to do this, but it turns out the solution is very simple. After one step, you get:

```
0 49 0 49 0 49 0 49 0 49 0 49 0 49 0 49 0 49
```

which is just 9 commands to print ASCII number 49, so "111111111" is output.

Answer (score 1):

### C, score ~10^26 (100000000000000004764729344)

```
main(){printf("%f",1E26);}
```

Apparently float failes there a little. [Tested there](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php).

Answer (score 1):

## [beeswax](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beeswax), <del>909090</del> 823543

The new solution just computes `7^7`, which is `85547` smaller than the old solution.

```
_7FB{
```

Explanation:

```
_       [0,0,0]•       create bee
 7      [0,0,7]•       push 7 on lstack
  F     [7,7,7]•       set all stack values to 1st value
   B    [7,7,823573]•  1st=1st^2nd
    {                  output lstack 1st to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BotEngine](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Bot-Engine), floor(10<sup>65</sup>/9)

```
v
e1
ldddddd<
ldddddd<
ldddddd<
ldddddd<
ldddddd<
>ddddP
```

This is probably the largest number of `d` instructions I've ever used in a single BotEngine program.

Answer (score 1):

## [x86 MS-DOS .COM file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file), score 111,111,111,111

Hex dump of the 11 byte .COM file (to reverse the hex dump, pass it into `xxd -r -seek -256`):

```
0100: b4 02 b2 31 b1 0c cd 21 e2 fc c3                   ...1...!...
```

Unassembled using `debug`:

```
0100 B402     MOV AH,02         ; prepare to print character to stdout
0102 B231     MOV DL,31         ; ASCII '1' to be printed
0104 B10C     MOV CL.0C         ; counter=12
0106 CD21     INT 21            ; print
0108 E2FC     LOOP 0106         ; repeat until counter is 0
010A C3       RET               ; end
```

Answer (score 1):

## Binary-Encoded Golfical, floor(10<sup>14</sup>/9)

Hexdump of binary encoding:

```
00 90 01 00 31 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 1D
```

Original image:

[image]

Magnified 80x, with color labels:

[image]

Explanation: Stores 49 (the code point of the digit `1`), prints it as a character 7 times, then turns around and prints it seven more times before terminating.

Answer (score 1):

## [ForceLang](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/ForceLang), 10<sup>13</sup>

```
io.write 1e13
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Reng v.3.3](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Assorted-Programming-Languages/tree/master/Reng), score 104976

[Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)

```
I²²n~
```

Prints

```
104976
```

This squares `I` (18) twice, yielding 104976. `n` prints this, and `~` terminates.

## Reng v.2.2, score 101010101010

```````
{An}``````~
```````

### Previously, score 96549157373046880

```
Z{ZZ**}#xxxxxxn~
```

Prints `96549157373046880`.

Comment: https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Assorted-Programming-Languages/tree/master/Reng

Answer (score 1):

## [Cy](https://github.com/cyoce/Cy), score 134217728

```
8 9 ^ :<
```

`8 9` pushes a 9 and an 8 to the stack (duh), `^` computes `8 ^ 9` (exponent, not xor), `:<` prints it.

This was not intended to be a golfing language, but this answer ended up pretty short compared to "real" languages. I didn't even need exponential notation!

Answer (score 1):

### AWK, 1e21

I didn't see an `AWK` answer, so here's mine.

Since a 'full program' was requested, this is the best I could come up with (full program is a bit fuzzy in `AWK`).

```
awk '{$0=1e21}1'<<<1
```

If we don't consider how the program is called as part of the program, then the score could be dropped to about 1e13 using:

```
 '{$0=1e13}1'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 100000000000

One digit shorter than the current python 3

```
print(1e11)
```

prints 1*(10^11)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), score 100

```
³
```

Prints `100` when [counting as 2 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%C2%B3) in UTF-8.

[Try it Online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrM&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Carrot](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/), 11111

```
1^*4

1     //"1" is pushed into the stack
 ^    //The stack is finished
  *   //Multiply or duplicate string operator (in this case it is the latter)
   4  //Duplicate the string 5 times (4+1)
```

`"1"` is pushed into the stack. Then the `*` operator duplicates the string `5` times, not `4` times because the `*` operator on strings always duplicates the strings `1` time more than what is stated, because duplicating it once is meaningless and hence it is removed. So the program outputs `11111`.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 9223372036854775807

I know they're not the shortest for PHP but..

#### 9223372036854775807

```
<?=PHP_INT_MAX;
```

#### 10000000000000000000

```
<?=str_pad(1,20,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [7](https://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 16031, language postdates challenge

```
1603
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/7#@29oZmD8/z8A)

It's unclear what "must be encoded in ASCII or UTF-8" means in 7. The most obvious meaning is that I have to write each command as a single character, and encode its name in ASCII (this is particularly suitable here, because that's an input encoding that the 7 interpreter understands). In this case, the best I can do is 16031 (the first character here is a literal that's never executed, thus could be any octal digit; `0603` outputs 06031, but leading zeroes are disallowed, so the best digit we can use here is 1).

### Explanation

A 7 program is basically a sequence of literals that are pushed to the stack, unescaping them in the process; thus the "initial run" of the program is always fairly boring and just puts things on the stack. Then the rightmost stack element is executed (while leaving it on the stack), repeatedly until the program exits.

Although all the commands that can occur in literals have names, some of the commands that can appear as the result of unescaping don't. The usual convention I use for this on PPCG is to bold "active" commands (which do something interesting when executed), and leave "passive" commands (which just push an active command) unboldened. The four active commands that don't have names are then given the same name as the corresponding passive command, and thus I rely on the font to distinguish. 7's "stack" is a little strange, relying on separators `|` between elements (which are manipulated as though they were a character in the language).

```
||           1603    Initial stack and program; 6 is active, 103 are passive
|103                 Result after the program's initial run
|103         103     (implicit) Top stack element is copied to the program
|1031        03      1 appends 1 to the stack
716031       3       0 escapes the top stack element and removes the | before it
                     3 prints output, and exits if the stack is low
```

The output in this case is `716031`. The first step in producing output is to check to see if it needs escaping (the algorithm for this is fairly complex, but typically boils down to making active commands passive, and enclosing passive sections in **`7`** … **`6`**). In most of my 7 programs, it does (due to containing anonymous commands), but all the commands seen there have names (unsurprisingly, because we escaped it manually on the previous line), so no escaping is necessary. Next, the first character output in the entire program (here, **`7`**) specifies the output format (7 means "the same as the input", so the output will be printed as a sequence of octal digits in ASCII). Finally, the remaining characters, `16031`, will be printed directly (shown here without the bold because one they're printed, they aren't commands any more, just characters).

Interestingly, the victory condition is different from a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), and that actually mattered. It's possible to write a smaller program that produces numerical output longer than itself: `163` outputs `71631` (basically because it doesn't escape explicitly, and implicit escaping by the **`3`** command always prepends a 7 to the output). However, in this case, although the program is shorter, the output is larger, so using a longer program gave a smaller score.

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp (GCL), 1586013445029888

```lisp
(princ(exp 35))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 11111, language postdates challenge

```
1j₅w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@2@Y9aiptfz/fwA)

Just makes five copies of `1` and prints them.

Answer (score 1):

### [Check](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/check-lang), score 1000010000

```
>10000pp
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 1 byte

```
T
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=T&input=&warnings=0&hex=0)

In Pyke, as well as in Pyth, `T` is a constant pre-initialised to `10`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 106735757048926755512911448358783973263883108352

48 digits, 46 bytes.

```
(((()()()){})){({}[()]<(({({}[()])}{}){})>)}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fAwg0QVCzuhaINaprozU0Y200NGBMzVqgBBDZgRj//wMA) (but not really because it will error with a segment fault).

This uses the common triangular method, `({{}[()]})`, but applies it recursively on the previous result. It starts with 6 as both the counter and the total and starts the loop, first decrementing the counter, then replacing the total with `2*triangle(total)`. Repeat a few times and it gets exponential, with each repetition roughly doubling the amount of digits.

Python code used to calculate the total:

```
def tri(t):
    return (t)*(t-1)/2

def f(n,t):
    for _ in range(n):
        t = tri(t)*2
    return t

print(len(str(int(f(6,6)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzBCsIwEETv@xV766ZExAo9CH6LCE3qgmzLdjz062MCFXynmeEx647XYtdSppQZroJwI654wseNa@8Fp0s4D0TNyWLx5@TF@cFq7E@bk9gxN8D3464f/v9AtLoa5J1MNri0nGWMY6jEbtJZsXWhlC8)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 10000000

10 million (8 digits) printed in 7 bytes:

```php
<?=1e7;
```

Almost 2.5 years and I am the first to think of that? Amazing.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 10000000

```perl6
1e7.say
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/98w1VyvOLHy/38A)

I can't see any Perl6 solutions, so for completeness...

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 8 bytes

```
8^9|Echo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/3yLOssY1OSP//38A)

Outputs `134217728`.

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) `-hr`, 10

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//@f6////7oZRQA)

### Explanation

```
\n  # Push the newline character onto the stack (Ord code 10)

-hr # Print the item raw (i.e. as a number)
```

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 100

```
d.
```

Pushes d and prints as integer. Fortunately 100 is a letter in the Keg code page.

Output is `100`.

Other solution just for fun and has a larger amplitude(also 2 bytes):

```
ā
```

Output is `257`
[TIO](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/Re//fwA)

Comment: @FlipTack Thank you. Remember to also remind [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142230/85052) answer.

Comment: [10, using `-hd` and a newline](https://tio.run/##y05N//@f6////7oZRQA "Keg – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), ~1.23e186

Prints `1234…95969798`, the concatenation of all integers from 1 to 98.

```
,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Exeunt][Enter Ajax and Page]Page:You is the sum ofyou a cat.Open heart.Is you worse twice the square ofthe sum ofa big big big cat a pig?If soLet usAct I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCsIwEER/ZT6g5AN6EQ89FAQFT1J62MZtG9GkJhtavz4mCnrYZRjmDROWe0qV2t9oq9SJJs5aC9panTVbLqJrNo5W@q6xwh4lCrJXlHRfXn1xESZAZkaID7jxlQ2CJlHHhS1mJi@qDSj@6nxgyGo0f4lnJM8Z@uOEwUy/yzW5bDHTrh0R3IEFMXxGqpTe)

After many iterations, here is a version without any spare characters. The code is 186 characters, and the output is 187 characters.

Comment: [Abusing integer overflow gets 8e153.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248205/25180)

Answer (score 1):

## [Intcode](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/5), 100000000000000000000000000000000

```
2,7,7,7,4,7,99,10000000000000000
```

This is almost certainly sub-optimal, given all it does is square the number given at the end.

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), <s>100,000,000</s> 11,111

```
1a5o
```

**Explanation**

```
1a5o # Output "1" five times
```

I slightly misunderstood the question at first — here's my original 8-byte solution:

```
1a1o1s8o
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 1000 or 1111111

```
1e3
1cy7.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fMNWYyzC50lxP@/9/AA)

First the boring method just printing 1000, or making an infinite number of 1s and clipping it to the length of the code+1.

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 52^7, 12 bytes

```python
print(52**7)
```

Edit 1: (Rip 11-ception)

After (embarrassingly) miscounting bytes, I'm back with the smaller version that turned out to be necessary. 52^7 is 1,028,071,702,528, which (at my count) is 13 bytes, and 13>12.
Of course, if you could write things straight to STDOUT, you could get away with 5**6 or 15,625.

Comment: Isn't it 13 bytes?

Comment: Oops - gotta go fix that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 1000010000.

- Filename: `10000.e.p` (9 bytes)
- Content: empty (0 bytes)

  - Total: 9 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Vr/U9u4Ev/df4UQIbETnNghbQFH9DgK185RcgO9d/deQxljK8SDY3tsJxCS3L/eW0l2YschhV7buce0sS3trj672l19tc2o/9nyB4HjUlmRpYjGSKVDYzgwo1ukac2mQe8DP4zR6dHV4ekpOTLicUDRDY0t3@uhg4ZNRw1v6LqoeVDWy2VeCwIHpmcXaxNZvx1@eEtwSU7p1GAukFUppQl71PZn4kWd4RTF72fv/ry6@PCGNDVtJy38rXPx7s/T/14ddc7Pj48@EN2wzIgiXJr8fHjx9uo/x@cX7zpn@7XxDCPHk8cK19JHgR859wb7qP1sGDQyrTnj/1by0cHQNWOKoj7j8oMY3u780I4C14kN03XMCKk3qFKa6DVc@gnPKqTCnhXj7PfT06P3b8h@vh2ZNW4bUd/pxRyIjRh9UkCtvo9KmwpvXVf4Z@z7yHdtUN2JkZ5IoyPTRXgD9Uw3ong6naBVtDNoNW631YoexX07rEi9oWfFju8h8xrMKA@iG2UShI4XI0zD0A@RjjCCUi5A1hRjtmCB/orkkMbbljJxerJzPez1aEgIxsqk54cW7bnDqC8rBtAQGahjGk7h4ToeRQm1YgAn1LeJpsBjGHoIHobl@hFNWKBNiyTkjNra@AsjrKTNYXAMUHkSDa9ljOrVEt7GGCAZvODjJ3RZRbxo3uLM9l3XDDViGUmTYJi5VgNzfJ0in/BnFNOgVmNNzz8PCH8149Ra/NOY1xPNmC1EZo0xkRDKssBnlkvK2NeJrl3Tu5UtzpRAtQjZaU6n8l6bWOWy1Sb6jsK4fj7@5d0Zo6ODIB4TzB94Lp5g/sCF9hBKrYF5JfdjGcwVxaZ1u433sZIvjpwHuigOIXZl9hNRavOigQmeqnFMwskkaRPFAIeFTcRsgahp9VFkhQ5Ej98Tn6E/jMEvpM1NVJdCatq@547Bfc1owNOEGaN2u/Khc3jxPuO18DQDJzZd2csaSX75ok28ctlrkz1NeS17tZ2msu8tWdca2Hm2LrwiJHtg4h0FbMxeXqYvr5KXVlrVegEvKc/evEFda8Jzg@y9FI/dDBVw6VqWTdf25nxNwafrO8nzVb5joQNoaLpJPwUhHYk@m0nZWjl9YWH4uqTtyyUNQhinBFym0H1hvJKmKOWyEElsP2YCwd0TFoi3TyKO@G8Jc5tB57MAy9aIOFs0xIgWYv5q1BsKL0sjALsLXIx6lsZGD@Etq@vh7RxEY8kIQnGBusRD5/jsTR76os1VLc4k7k@SgiXmdz@hN50Pb94fHp133h6fH@e88O4274V//FpZ9Ixz4/khvbKBPjDjvggrj0YxixUR1CUwLDZxgm5eB1lvkoVXN9nACWECKQhEovrdNqrfw//xNoLAqT9gNEWYwdAPyk1sZHk3UTT2YvMeicQdhP5NaA4SmiT/J0ZO21dVYzV8cJGlQqJPOON9LNT5q/Hp4939@OGy1JhkJEKeZNU6aOtybW9EGtbUvcsauAfPKh8dW@QReLm8JGVj/gHsIrEINuZQXQ@hJNmwonqdOZlipK5SSoyd4oKGA2hY2KQrYcQyjuyQeROqbjgHoKOjqsoEfEwQpVac43MujUylTV3KBv1VtbP527wNEI8LsPw8LHADOXpY4FIOtHV4gFbVlbWgVpAstFYzgIvYvOdh8wZkXavMwwftPEuqUOuFkSv1BlUCXZIpm2Xe/Yi0dmvABwK3dEgBmTrWrwBEVDZYpTc40Ixc0RKEZXEwrPF0I3dxt@t1sQIUj0ER8PP137AHnHwPZK2/4APDJqP1BgHIWMk2NI@sh0uSUC042RSJsfM5m4KgP5/F@hhxtufSeQQDZhRjgoV2QeurYqgaRq7TFiqTgsoooxGbQCaT2C6uX@3D1ACWBtSKqY2OOyfAuOSh6ewqkb7sKl8rGUEC92AmM6SPOVJWI5hM5JuNbohufCMg1zCA3T4JxYsiCvWHwWjttlOnK5eTl/aL3S8aZq3cLD7HC4Yx8vwY3mJ6Q8McxFk2uh7DguxRWq62dpfCqtiWEz3a3GoXz5q2oNeTbcRAjqq6VpMXWJ/pnEuNZ8a2FQN3dFO1R08Ndet5Q0wuzTwpwUKr6xJs9Lz2v2FqHz0ltYtZCkxL2mx4ih4aTVga12p5m9yRR@YnmeK8sZwC6EItie7Wwu/hxZqVp3kYLx1Y6xUpaV7R7Eo64yXD6wD4a/oqCeHzOonVx0HBPRQWRzm3n4doyNKVTXuw1LT5WhRIlzLWsjQ@neDrXKUaB8paW919cTxbbZQvq4rQnb02Dp7kso84bQIAWliZgFYoev8NFSXNJU3vr8mGvKxGO1fQhF7@Cu1XETUfNxFpFmx0f/00A42/p4HGqwx08O8w0PiJBnr4ngZ6uCYF@xDy7zDQwxMNZObz7gqK@HnZsk/NgPygBeWgAI21vkH4tuTqgV5eAL8kjPprRnmbGy23j2MU91zEdoi2avNDL4isfcnKS9637Bq1H2Vz9R8CVb@0qF9maLMV9FLZ8mr@G@q38Q/1q/6ojig9E@hIJ@vyyaj5XYBzYCO9CuJzK7rSPnqgoa/azsiJHN9bNz0CpGTUPBjpr9kkadRsjHRln7/qjVFz/Vxp6//aSlv/wEpbCyttrbHSYjc7zV0by/vFZz6s6MKQRoHv2Y53g@omn9V@l31jvl3@x69iuxzdUI@G7CSUHfjMj2/EDrla6XnmgOZPGPnBEFhEDERcDz4i8SGB7@9mtk@lVIAk7SP@PnBs26WoXJaSI4KtiJ3S6pub1cYM1JN8G6mHyENqjIY6UkdQFIdIPYqQpjd3Wi9evtrdQ5WPXa96WYG6m5AGqA4v5t0to4Z1DWm9BJH8zAknFbgkLw4ltqJu1xMUd7eMAjDDMqLCLdXIDToNqytV4C8zgItDJgMDdYXbMFGsByhBK35cW5lVmG2tPrVuoePBFSwaRWbIziAQO49APcelEluDEY1BpkST0gPr1BTQHXK1/rF3cllV@HKN6EicEj9GSo8TUlogZfzshwpibT54pnQMru/F1ONneQweMqP0jCUrRQjQ2XEM8xJc0oUJV/QbQut6DqF53yUdEDXq1cbqPYr84UJD8MvC2HPXTNe0k4rBsBko7QxFSrVcKJJaYoUh5jEBi9zliGBGygdEshJ@YkBktwhEBfDyFMa3CaTV2wCChu0WSMvTKB7TCSopF1TNf204JeNFV3zhok3YnorYNuFJdUGYGicxSEqt6peX@U2VIt@ClE0@C/WrzoaWiGbLBSnPYh9oiSBNFsY8W@QcCXJGRVqjvfR0haWijtIjaiWnhwXwkvAjAMWCoOd4puuOJREdkqR83mR@bdOwjoJ7OrDq/NKNEw3qjNqHiEpq7nM1cZ@OkRlS1Av9Aa/PVQ982@k54C8muoaG2Kj34V2H1cC/fhwH0X6jcePE/eF13fIHjV/eqh8Ck56Ydw/Ua@TESZvAkithO7hHR1pdkk7ODt8fE12DvzqtB9JF5/fzo2PyORsvnAZP7yykWnyAzUWT4Hi0mjOvIpKTSEpumrDzZ3EbSJZLcnpX6vD8l6v3h3/yu1XTKa9vaq1dRd1TFAUzdnGJhmDWBUj19CkPbIjrUTzUp6tCGkFET0U8T1lAqpRl2E@o2oD0KT5QtQQfXH56@YPh@8jA8wtfQ1YM3XZZLkNhWChcgLBbSD1r5QgEKjuDSp1O5SACFh8F4Is0dgZ0O7CC4fYoejBsSLlKVq/W9NFUlSoWm44L5mg1uYoV3elKalNvvWrt7rxs7UpsROnK9e5ktzvrKqVGV29UpkmHVCZmjV04mLEJmshIpgFjBUbiPhu7SDf3ioUDKDjpoIqYaDWR67MBHYBQu6KkwJJGBua9S72v7XQRbwQnjiZ6SoQaweILQEDAwpeYEqKKuM7QOb9glytOT0h6NoohNSlGh11panzizlhqsPteHUJ0JbnKxCWj0xNOxuevQMvVFKQr6cT5/c40My8VCa0FCY2cnYhUJjg7Jxeo5GRJZ6Li9CRbKCBjnnq2huwGSakp7r7BEyCpr8VNBKHBRicVL@wFqPREbg/hbnfLB/5Un0ki@y7ugdxso1z@zo7wh4K24BnTqI/U6PPf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bitcoin Cash Script (BitAuth IDE)](https://ide.bitauth.com/), 18 bytes

```bitcoin-cash-script
// Golfed
0x0340420f76769595
// The number 1000000000000000000 will be on top of stack

// Ungolfed
OP_DROP // clean up
<1000000> OP_DUP OP_DUP OP_MUL OP_MUL
// The number 1000000000000000000 will be on top of stack
```

[Opcodes reference](https://documentation.cash/protocol/blockchain/script#operation-codes-opcodes)

[Try it online!](https://alpha.ide.bitauth.com/import-template/eJylUEFOwzAQ_MrK4tgmJrRFjRAHCoIDqBElJ4Ii19kSQ2Jb8aYgVf07dpMDEkd82ZnZnZE1B3bmZI2tYCmriaxL41hVGG0ViZ7qSJo2DgA1KSlIGT0lbG0jCKd7Hg3e6MMZzSasQic7ZcOVj_OCFi16lHszNVh5JeSQQsfSw3HChvNAAhQk69KKKtDRuRlUyEQwD-dejmO4N80Oq0Lzb34x47OE7y4Xl4vlfDkvtF-_1Ai6b7fYwTn_8-BLNQ1sEYwGMhbMDhwJ-VnokznX72P6Oitvn9cZeFE2KDT0ttBXY-I1hHWe_RpP-eM4_vELdgzV9Naajnxp6Su7WT2UCU-Sks99DYFtsrsVe5uwPXbuVDc__gDSgZA8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2), score 117649

```
O^7 6
```

Outputs \${7}^{6}=117649\$

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyJPXjcgNiIsIiIsIjIuMCJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111, 53 bytes

```go
package main
func main(){for i:=1;i<55;i++{print(1)}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjdNCxKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuNJK85LBLA3N6rT8IoVMK1tD60wbU1PrTG3t6oKizLwSDUPN2lqIZqgZMLMA)

Prints to STDERR.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 1010

```
10.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39BA7/9/AA)

Same length as [Lynn's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67978/78410) but gives a smaller number by pushing two copies of 10 and (implicitly) printing them side-by-side.

Some fun alternatives include `n).` and `n(.`, which extract the charcode of newline from the string `"\n"` to get 10 (leaving an empty string at the bottom)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), >1E25, 25 bytes

```c
main(){printf("1%025u");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ8lQ1cDItFRJ07r2/38A)

Not determined, not sure if any env make it const result

Comment: Using TurboC(C in 16-bit) always result in 1E25+256

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 100

```
2ᴇ
2             (push 2 onto the stack)
 ᴇ            (raise 10 to the 2nd power)
              (implicitly print)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f6OGW9v//AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), score 120

`5P`

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=NVA=)

computes 5 factorial (120)

---

## <s>Itr, score 0</s>

The empty program in Itr prints `0` which has a length longer than the source code but is not positive.

Comment: I'd argue the empty program doesn't count.  It outputs 0 and its length is 0, and the constraint was that the output needs to be longer than its length (not equal).  Were Itr to default to outputting 1, I think it would qualify.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), score 1

```
/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWC_UhNJQLEwYA)

The Nibbles program "`/`" is 1 nibble or 0.5 bytes long, and outputs the value `1`.

```
/       # full program
/$$     # with implicit args added
/       # divide
 $      # the input (which is assigned with
        # a value of 100 if no input given)
  $     # by the input (also assigned to 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), score <strike>1073741824</strike> 100000

*-1073641824 points from noodle man*

```
&p1e5
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__JnAxZTUK)

#### Explanation

```
&p1e5
  1e5   # Push 1e5 to the stack
&p      # Print with newline
```

Comment: `&pⁿ7 10` for 10000000, and while you're at it `&p1e5` for 100000

Answer (score 1):

## Awk, 1000000

```
$0=1e6
```

Must be fed a newline.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 1028071702528

```
print(52**7)
```

One byte longer than Python 2, but the same approach.

EDIT: turns out my search wasn't exhaustive enough -- thanks, Neil.

Comment: `52**7` is only `1028071702528`.

Answer (score 0):

## Mumps, score 100000

```
W 1e5
```

Writes 10^5, or 100000. Had the newline not been optional, that would have added 2 more characters to the program:

```
W 1e7,!  ; this would output 10000000
```

Now that I mention it... it would be interesting to see how much would change on some of the winning answers if an explicit newline was required - especially the 0 or 1 byte answers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 111,111,111,111

Lower than the other python answers

```
print'1'*12
```

Answer (score 0):

### [MSM](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MSM), 10101010

```
.;.;.01
```

7 byes for an 8 byte output. Repeatedly duplicates and concatenenates starting with `10`.

Answer (score 0):

## Visual Basic .NET, 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 (86 ones)

```
Module A
Sub Main
System.Console.Write(New System.String("1"C,86))
End Sub
End Module
```

Oh dear. (This is shorter than using a loop, unless there's some fast way to do that that I don't know about.)

Comment: You don't need to write `System.`.

Answer (score 0):

### k4, 10000

```
$ cat a.k; echo
_1e4
$ wc -c a.k
4 a.k
$ q a.k </dev/null
10000
$
```

The input file is missing its trailing newline, but that doesn't matter to the interpreter. The language's default behavior on reading code files is to print the output of any statement which is not explicitly suppressed, so all I have to do is create the number. Exponential notation creates floats though, so I have to floor it to create an integer, otherwise the output would be `10000f` (the default representation of a float that has no fractional part).

Answer (score 0):

### dc, 117649

```
$ cat a.dc; echo
7 6^p
$ wc -c a.dc
5 a.dc
$ dc -f a.dc
117649
$
```

Inspired by WGroleau's comment on the question.

Comment: Six to the power of something?  Three bytes code.  What happens with five instead of six?

Comment: Never mind—I didn't see the seven space

Answer (score 0):

### Fortran 77, 36 ones

```
^Iwrite(*,'(36i1)'),(1,i=1,36)
^Iend

(where ^I represents the TAB character.  This is the first Fortran
program I've written or have even seen that uses TABs)
```

### FORTRAN IV, 54 ones

```
      PRINT1,(1,I=1,54)
    1 FORMAT(54I1)
      END
```

Both solutions write a newline after the number.  Note that if you're using a line printer to look at the output, the first "1" will be interpreted as a page-feed and the numbers in the programs will need to be increased by 1, to 37 for Fortran 77 and to 55 for Fortran IV.

Answer (score 0):

## [Insomnia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40073/making-future-posts-runnable-online-with-stack-snippets/41868#41868), 129

```
i
```

Apart from `i` (105), `r` (115) or `}` (125) outputs the same result, since the position of the bit pointer doesn't matter when it's the last state-changing operation.

Answer (score 0):

### C, 1407260946921681491238744 (25 digits)

24 characters:

```
main(){printf("%lu%u");}
```

The output is nondeterministic (which may disqualify this submission).  After a few million runs, I've only gotten 25 digit output.  Some day I should figure out what GCC is (setting up a.out to be) sprinkling past the end of the stack for `printf()` to use here.

Answer (score 0):

### Ceylon, 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 (42 digits)

This was my second try:

```ceylon
shared void run(){print("1".repeat(42));}
```

A program with length 41, prints a string of 42 ones.

---

My first, more complicated try printed  112589990684262411529215046068469761152921504606846976 (54 digits):

`````ceylon
shared void run(){print("``2^50````2^60````2^60``");}
`````

This program has a length of 53 bytes.

Ceylon integers go just up to right under 2^63, which gives us only 19 digits. Due to the boilerplate here we need to concatenate three of them, which is done by the use of string templates (the contents of ``` `` ... `` ``` inside a string literal are evaluated as an expression and then converted into a string).
Then it was simply a point of looking up the powers of two with (relatively) smallest first digits (2^50 starts with 1125, 2^60 with 1152), such that the length of them sums to 54. I guess combining other powers might make the program slightly shorter, but this still will not beat the simple one above.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, score 10,000,000,000

```
echo 1e10;
```

Assuming the opening/closing tags don't count, otherwise it's

```
<?=echo 1e13;
```

And if we allow non-PHP, we have `<?=1e7` and `1e3` as options.  Taking the first answer as the "most correct" of the four.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pylons](https://github.com/morganthrapp/Pylons-lang), 10

```
B
```

How it works:

```
B # Push B to the stack. (pre-initialized to 10)
  # The stack is implicitly printed at the end of the program.
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 100 ones, 23 chars

```
<?=str_repeat("1",1E2);
```

Comment: @MorganThrapp Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: @MorganThrapp bytes.... ok, now.

Comment: `<?=str_repeat("1",23);` works for score `11111111111111111111111`.

Comment: `<?=str_repeat(1,21);` 21 ones, 20 bytes - `<?=str_pad(1,20,0);` - a one plus 19 zeroes, 19 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## Mathcad, 3 "bytes", 4 digits, 5040

Updated version.  See text of Original version for suppression of decimal places discussion.   As the original version, used one integer raised to power of another, I've also included what I think is the smallest number that meets the criterion.

[image]

---

**Original (and wrong!) Version ...**

*Here's two Mathcad expressions (you may regard the "3" version as even more cheaty than the 8 version, hence my providing the two versions ...)*

[image]

Mathcad doesn't have a "text" file as such.  It operates more as a 2D whiteboard, where you can either type characters and operators onto a "worksheet", or enter them via a single-click toolbar.  Mathcad stores the worksheet as an xml file.  From a user perspective, however, typing "cat" counts as 3 distinct characters, which I'm taking to be the equivalent of "bytes" for the purposes of golfing; pi is single character as well.   An operator, such as "=" (evaluate), "+" (add) or ":=" (define), also counts as a "byte".

There are also a number of settings, such as the number of decimal places shown displaying a real number, which are available from a dialog box.   If, for example, setting the number of decimals to zero counts as a 0 "byte" operation, then π= is the shortest one I can think of.  If this is regarded as cheating from a golfing perspective, then the exponent version should meet the spirit of the competition.

Comment: Nice answer, but the goal of this challenge is to print an integer that has more *digits* than the program has bytes, e.g. print a 3-digit number with a 2 byte program. Could you please fix this?

Comment: Doh!  yabinm (Yet Another Brain In Neutral Moment).

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 30903154382632612361920641803529

```
SELECT''||POWER(9,33)FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Desmos, 6561

```
9^4
```

equals 6561

#### previous answer, 1048576

```
2^{20}
```

equals 1048576

Answer (score 0):

## Forth, 1073741824 (2^30)

```
1 30 << .
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/C31u)

If the result could be left on the stack:

#### 100663296

```
96 20 <<
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Turtlèd](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/turtl-d/), 100000000000

```
11:[*'0l]'1
```

`11`- set register to 11

`:` move right by amount in register

`[*'0l]` loop: `[*   ]`- while current cell is not `*`, `'0`- write zero to cell, `l` -move left

`'1`- write one

Answer (score 0):

## ///, score 111111111111

```
/./111/....
```

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=Ly4vMTExLy4uLi4&input=)

`/./111/` removes itself and replaces every `.` with `111`, so `....` becomes `111111111111`.

Answer (score 0):

## [DUP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/DUP), 100100

```
'd$..
```

Put character d on stack, duplicate it, print its value twice.

[Online DUP interpreter](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html).

[My Julia implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/m-lohmann/DUPEsolang.jl), with comprehensive language description.

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 10000000000000000

```
puts [expr 1e16]
```

Outputs:

```
10000000000000000.0
```

The integer part is 1 and 16 zeros.

http://rextester.com/RWNL80143

Comment: Doesn't that make this answer invalid?

Comment: @LegionMammal978: Waiting feedback from question's author. `1e17` is still an integer!

Comment: "1e+17" has a length of 5, while your program has a length of 16

Comment: @12Me21: I don't have a `+` in `1e17`!

Comment: The output does

Comment: @LegionMammal978: I hope my answer is now valid

Comment: @12Me21: I hope my answer is now valid

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>16713480</s> <s>1111111</s> 10000

```
?1E4
```

Boring.

Previous Answers: `?-#CYAN`, `?"1"*7`

Answer (score 0):

### Underload, score 100000100000

```
(100000):*S
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Syms](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Syms), <s>999980001</s> 1111111 (noncompeting)

```
1:7;*>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/syms#@29oZW6tZff/PwA)

Answer (score 0):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 3628800 (10!)

```
a/P
o@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@5@oH8CV7/D/PwA)

#### Explanation

```
a   Push 10.
/   Reflect to SE. Switch to Ordinal.
    Reflect off bottom right corner, move back NW.
/   Reflect to W. Switch to Cardinal.
a   Push 10.
    Wrap around to the end of the first line.
P   Compute 10! = 3628800.
/   Reflect to NW. Switch to Ordinal.
    Immediately reflect off top boundary, move SW.
o   Implicitly convert the result to a string and print it.
    Reflect off bottom left corner, move back NE.
/   Reflect to S. Switch to Cardinal.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Braingolf, 20

Oh hey look I can golf it now thanks to niladic stuff

```
+
```

Niladic `+` (ie run when the stack is empty) pushes 20 to the stack, implicit output.

## Braingolf, 100

Just throwing in my 2 cents (or 2 bytes, as it were)

```
#d
```

Pushes the charcode of the character 'd' to the stack, which is 100. Braingolf will automatically print the last element of the stack when the code terminates if there is no semicolon present in the code.

#### Note:

As with every Braingolf submission thus-far on PPCG, this is non-competing, as the language was created on 3rd May 2017.

Answer (score 0):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 28 byte, 111111111111111111111111111111 (29 ones)

```
x=29
lbla
print 1
x-1
if x a
```

Ugh! Looping is expensive!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/silos#@19ha2TJlZOUk8hVUJSZV6JgyFWha8iVmaZQoZD4/z8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de)/[QBasic](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack)/VBA, 10000 4 bytes

Takes no input and outputs `10000`to the console.

```vb
?1E4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/397Q1eT/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 1e66

Shortest *full program* I could make:

```java
interface A{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(1e66);}}
```

With 65 bytes, this program outputs:

```java
1e66
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJ/v8/M68ktSgtMTlVwbG6uCSxJDNZoSw/M0UhNzEzTyO4pCgzLz06NlGzOriyuCQ1Vy@/tESvAChYomGYamamaV1b@/8/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), score 10,000,000,000,000 (10<sup>13</sup>)

```
main{[10^13]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfz/PzcxM6862tAgztA4tvb/fwA)

## Röda statement, score 1,000,000 (10<sup>6</sup>)

```
[10^6]
```

The program is executed using this command (the flags are required to execute the program, so they are free):

```
röda -e "[10^6]" -n
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog(SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 1e+15

```
?-write(1e15).
```

Outputs (surprise surprise) `1.0e+15`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/3163vCizJFXDMNXQVFPv/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), score 65

```
A
```

Pushes the ASCII value for `A` (65). Implicit output.

Answer (score 0):

## Commodore 64/VIC 20 BASIC, 5 PETSCII characters (excluding the carriage return)

```
 0?1E5
```

Some caveats here; firstly, Commodore BASIC adds in a white space before printing any number or numeric variable; secondly, there is no concept of true integer types in Commodore BASIC (I think that applies to all variants through to BASIC 7 on the Commodore 128); and finally `LIST`ing the program will show its un-obfuscate form, and add in a white space after each line number, so the above symbolic listing becomes:

```
0 PRINT1E5
```

So, on that basis, it could be that this is automatically disqualified if these caveats are taken into account. Does my initial *golfed* version count as a valid entry?

Answer (score 0):

## Momema, score 10000000001000000000

```
01000000000-8*0-8*0
```

### Explanation:

```
0  1000000000  #  [0] = 1000000000
-8 *0          #  print num [0]
-8 *0          #  print num [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 10

```
Ａ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjIx,v=2)

`Ａ` pushes 10 to the stack, then Canvas inplicitly prints the item at the top of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <s>10^52</s> 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 (~1.1e46)

```
var i:word;begin for i:=1to 46do write(1)end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsTk7M0U0rSP7/vyyxSCHTqjy/KMU6KTU9M08hLR8kYGtYkq9gYpaSr1BelFmSqmGomZqXovf/PwA)

Obvious one, I missed it somehow at first, thinking it would be bigger number.

---

Previous approach - 10^52 (10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)

```pascal
uses sysutils;begin write(1,Format('%.52D',[0]))end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsTk7M0U0rSP7/v7Q4tVihuLK4tCQzp9g6KTU9M0@hvCizJFXDUMctvyg3sURDXVXP1MhFXSfaIFZTMzUvRe//fwA)

[`Format`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/format.html) is a function in `sysutils` which gives a string from specified formatting string and array of arguments. Formatting string works pretty much like in C: `%` starts the part which will be replaced, `D` means integer in decimal format, `.52` for `D` means the number will be written with at least 52 digits; since `0` has less than 52 digits, it is left-padded with zeroes. `1` is written before it to make a valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 10²⁸ 10000000000000000000000000000 (28 bytes)

```rust
fn main(){print!("{}",1e28)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDqbpWSccw1chCs/b/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 1000

```
aC@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/R2eH/fwA)

Huh, another classic I apparently never answered.

Because the number must be strictly *longer* than the program (so a 3 byte program requires a 4 digit number), this is as small as we can go (but there [are two ways](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/98w0uH/fwA) to do it).

Answer (score 0):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 1e+24

Verbosity killed the wren. Calulates 10^24.

```
System.write(10.pow(24))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9Kzfv/P7iyuCQ1V6@8KLMkVcPQQK8gv1zDyERT8/9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 100,000,000,000

```sql
SELECT 1e11
```

Note that the shorter `PRINT 1e10` doesn't seem to work in this case; in the SQL versions I tested (2012 to 2017) it keeps the output in the exponential format (`1e+010`), which I assume isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 100

```
2^
```

Explanation

```
 ^ % 10 to the power of ...
2  % ... 2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 137438953472 (2^37)

```
print 2**37
```

Code is 11 bytes long, output is 12 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

## x86-16, IBM PC DOS, 111,111,111

```
B8 0A31     MOV  AX, 0A31H  ; AH = 0AH (write chars * CL), AL = '1' 
B1 09       MOV  CL, 9      ; display 9 times  
CD 10       INT  10H        ; call BIOS 
C3          RET             ; return to DOS
```

This is based on [@krubo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67921/what-is-the-smallest-positive-base-10-integer-that-can-be-printed-by-a-program-s/68337#68337) above, but 3 bytes shorter.  This uses the PC BIOS's `INT 10`,`0AH` function for output since it will repeat the same char `CL` number of times, saving the need for a  `LOOP` (-2 bytes).  Also, `AL` and `AH` can be initialized at the same time (-1 byte).

Answer (score 0):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 24 ones

```
print*,("1",i=1,23)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8vKMrMK9HS0VAyVNLJtDXUMTLW5ErNS/n/HwA)

Better Fortran score by avoiding formats entirely.

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), <s>362880</s> <s>161280</s> 100100

```
#2;J4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X9nI2svk/38A)

J4 defults to base 2, and evaluates to 100 as a string. '100'+'100' = '100100'.

Answer (score 0):

## [MAWP 1.0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 76543210

```
8[1A!:].
```

As suggested by [Jo King.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=8%5B1A!%3A%5D.&input=)

## [MAWP 1.0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 152587890625

```
5!W!W!W!W:.
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=5!W!W!W!W%3A.&input=)

Comment: Wow, never thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

## [RGBDS](https://github.com/rednex/rgbds/) macros, 11,111,111,111,111,111,111,111

```
REPT 23
 PRINTI 1
ENDR
```

Answer (score 0):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), <s>100000000100000000</s> 100000000000000

```
A\10v
~000~!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/98xxtCgjKvOwMCgTvH/fwA)

This program is 12 bytes long and outputs a 15 byte number. It starts with 5 bits, discarding one and printing a copy of the bits each iteration.

BitCycle actually outputs in bits (ones and zeroes), which can be interpreted as a decimal number as above. It is normally interpreted in unary with the `-u` flag.

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle) `-u`, 60328467484514692442875165185

```
AB/00v  ~DDDDD@
~111 ~CD^
!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/9/RSd/AoExBoc4FBBy46gwNDRXqnF3iuBT///@vWwoA)

Honestly, not that much longer, but this takes a huge amount of time to execute. The code at 27 bytes, with the number at 29 digits long, which was the shortest of this format that I could find. Essentially, this repeatedly does the sum of 1 to n (as in the triangular numbers) on the same value, starting at `5`, which increases exponentially. Then it outputs the sum of all these numbers

Answer (score 0):

## [Rec](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Rec), 111111111111

<s>The space before `49` is required, otherwise the character will not display properly.</s> Well, it seems like it's a Python formatting issue.

```python
12[0:^\49p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVZLc9owEL77V@zQg@3yKE7SR2jpLZnprZPpjTgZgRfQxJU0kkyc6aR/nUoyEAMyZqpLYnb32/cniRe95OxyrTSZPcEYJmkQZDgHWbBHibNISL7oQYbTYmGktyRXGI8CMKdzh7qQDFYkL9DInpeolyjhGYEhZqA5TCWSJ@CFBj4HYjRojpBzLjoOQWhp7Ibufy1fKlh7KkUr/gY5MhdE/Ca2h87B/joxSilQBuEwubi8@vjp85frcF9zq63l9yEQlu3s@skZlva42gyIEMiyqPoQXETx@2TYpUxHu0Di@MgeTcHOQD0Fg/lesuMxhB88kTq8iU2qO4akDeH@/iRE/wyIkQehNA2tVShoL@Xkb5m25vvV56oHq31vvXbX1psxWrU5fPAPEeO67sPfWFntxS9ZYNDmJ/X4kYQqhB8sw/JGSi6jsGBTkhM2M1s1lcY7ahW21mzigc5xhTkc9tY5pYulNhK7dF2PfLO71t6fdQVtRs9F4eC2cZzQ7x/rp379KkA32setzampzaNFgvGuDN1k5IzMPDekY1vkz8bO8ZYCa@ixV9mUvrShN8PZ48jwOPaKBF2gR7IZZ5qywzF6B7dcVpS8oGwBopCCK1RtA/HTMxBCWuapjXTrWN018UadyigThTZgrWiiMSYDZeoyW8q96FoBZRMpvaiB0hllA9OGLErioKmL4Tm3QD/5b6rnMovK9kSUb32Jsjv6m5TRsAfuCoubNtWq7m47@5UOqFKCzLCJt5xJ30cOVUfmYfTH6rzG8OcN9TXc0G5rRlNPRtuHxTFZGvNKaJOwvLsDO5WHbXU1fDZao70L1lq@QmjITenNTMXmIwTDpMHhQr7RDJYzFBpu3B/KGRAFtS6bKC0cxlXPtLQLSS11b589krAFHmRun0teUg8OdiAODlugRuDJ67gHWFJtpzyo3Uju9RYEG5qUnU5nnVxMhqOH@6trka7Nd1B/9sXrfw)

Answer (score 0):

## [ForWhile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ForWhile), score 1111111

`7[49#)`

prints `1` 7 times

[online interpeter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=N1s0OSMp)

## ForWhile, score 76543210

`8(47+#)`

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=OCg0NysjKQ==)

For loop printing decreasing characters for `8+47` (ascii `'7'`) downwards to `1+47` (ascii `'0')

Answer (score 0):

## Kotlin, score 123456789101112131415161718192021222324

```
fun main()=(1..24).forEach{print(it)}
```

probably could be improved but not sure how

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 10000000

```perl
say 1e7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLBMNX8//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Answer (score 0):

### HP‑41C series, 1

This submissions presumes there are no other programs in program memory.
We merely need to increase the number of displayed digits *before* placing the number on top of the stack.
The default setting is to display and round to (up to) 4 places after the radix mark (`FIX 4`).

```
01♦LBL⸆T           5 Bytes    global label requires 4 + (length of string) Bytes
02 FIX 9           2 Bytes    display 9 digits after radix point
   NULL            1 Byte     invisible Null byte before numbers
02 1               1 Byte     push 1 on top of the stack (X ≔ 1)
```

shows, if flag 29 is set (the default),

```
 1.000000000
```

or, if flag 29 is cleared,

```
 1,000000000
```

If you want to *print* the number with an HP 82143A Printer, append a `VIEW X` command (2 Bytes) or shift the printer’s mode switch to the `TRACE` position (which will, however, print all the other commands, too).